# ShinyAlert in Rmd Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to render a popup in an Rmd flexdashboard.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include= FALSE}
library(shinyalert)
```


```{r}
  useShinyalert(  )
  actionButton("helpBtn", "Help")
```


```{r}
  observeEvent(input$helpBtn, {
  shinyalert(title = "Help Me!", text = "Please contact your instructor")})

```
````

The button shows up but when clicked it does not show the popup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the same issue, and I don't think you can do this with `shinyalert` because of the need for `useShinyAlert()` - adding extra dependencies into Rmd documents doesn't seem to be supported very well.

A workaround is to use `sendSweetAlert` from the `shinyWidgets` package:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include= FALSE}
library(shinyWidgets)
```


```{r}
  actionButton("helpBtn", "Help")
```


```{r}
  observeEvent(input$helpBtn, {
  sendSweetAlert(session, title = "Help Me!", text = "Please contact your instructor")})

```
````

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your issue was resolved or not, but setting the `rmd` parameter in `useShinyalert` to `TRUE` should solve your problem.

`useShinyalert(rmd = TRUE)`